# Weight Normalisation causes Non-Leaf error with ADAM optimiser Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I am using a PyTorch model (model given in the end).

When I use

```
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=opt['base_lr'])
```

The code works fine.

However when I use,

```
def get_parameters(model, bias=False):
    for m in model.modules():
        if bias:
            if isinstance(m, nn.Conv2d):
              if m.bias is not None:
                yield m.bias
        else:
            if isinstance(m, nn.Conv2d):
              if m.weight is not None:
                yield m.weight


optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(
    [
        {'params': get_parameters(model, bias=False)},
        {'params': get_parameters(model, bias=True), 'lr': opt['base_lr'] * 2, 'weight_decay': 0},
    ],lr=opt['base_lr'])
```

A runtime error is thrown stating, `ValueError: can't optimize a non-leaf Tensor`

I understand the difference between [leaf and non-leaf tensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61851506/torch-optim-returns-valueerror-cant-optimize-a-non-leaf-tensor-for-multidime) and found that if I switch off weight normalisation in my model, no error is thrown even with the modified ADAM optimiser.
i.e replacing `layers.append(wn(m))` with `layers.append(m)` where `wn` is given by `from torch.nn.utils import weight_norm as wn` in my model definition prevents any error.

Indeed I checked using `is_leaf` and weight normalisation is making tensors Non-leaf.

Can someone help me how I can fix the problem while retaining Weight Normalisation?

My model is given below:

```
import torch
from torch.nn.utils import weight_norm as wn
import torch.nn as nn

def conv_layer(inc, outc, kernel_size=3, groups=1, bias=False, negative_slope=0.2, bn=False, init_type='kaiming', fan_type='fan_in', activation=False, pixelshuffle_init=False, upscale=4, num_classes=3, weight_normalization = True):

    layers = []
    
    if bn:
        m = nn.BatchNorm2d(inc)
        nn.init.constant_(m.weight, 1)
        nn.init.constant_(m.bias, 0)
        layers.append(m)
    
    if activation=='before':
            layers.append(nn.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=negative_slope, inplace=False))
        
    if pixelshuffle_init:
        m = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=inc, out_channels=num_classes * (upscale ** 2),
                                  kernel_size=3, padding = 3//2, groups=1, bias=True, stride=1)
        nn.init.constant_(m.bias, 0)
        with torch.no_grad():
            kernel = ICNR(m.weight, upscale, negative_slope, fan_type)
            m.weight.copy_(kernel)
    else:
        m = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=inc, out_channels=outc,
     kernel_size=kernel_size, padding = (kernel_size-1)//2, groups=groups, bias=bias, stride=1)
        init_gain = 0.02
        if init_type == 'normal':
            torch.nn.init.normal_(m.weight, 0.0, init_gain)
        elif init_type == 'xavier':
            torch.nn.init.xavier_normal_(m.weight, gain = init_gain)
        elif init_type == 'kaiming':
            torch.nn.init.kaiming_normal_(m.weight, a=negative_slope, mode=fan_type, nonlinearity='leaky_relu')
        elif init_type == 'orthogonal':
            torch.nn.init.orthogonal_(m.weight)
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError('initialization method [%s] is not implemented' % init_type)
    
    if weight_normalization: 
        layers.append(wn(m)) # <------ REMOVING THIS MAKES CODE EXECUTE WITH NO ERROR
    else:
        layers.append(m)
    
    if activation=='after':
            layers.append(nn.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=negative_slope, inplace=False))
            
    return nn.Sequential(*layers)

class Net(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        
        
        self.up4 = nn.PixelShuffle(4)
        self.up2 = nn.PixelShuffle(2)
        
        self.conv32x = nn.Sequential(        
                        conv_layer(1024, 128, kernel_size=3, groups=128, bias=True, negative_slope=1, bn=False, init_type='kaiming', fan_type='fan_in', activation=False, pixelshuffle_init=False, upscale=False, num_classes=False, weight_normalization = True),
                        conv_layer(128, 64, kernel_size=3, groups=1, bias=True, negative_slope=1, bn=False, init_type='kaiming', fan_type='fan_in', activation=False, pixelshuffle_init=False, upscale=False, num_classes=False, weight_normalization = True)
                        )
...
```